# Flash banner with clickTAG and clickTARGET

Tags: actionscript, flash, banner, clicktag

I need to adapt my swf banner so that will work with clickTAG and clickTARGET. Actionscript code is required to be

```
on (release) {
  if (clickTAG.substr(0,5) == "http:") {
    getURL(clickTAG, clickTARGET);
  }
}
```

and my HTML code looks like this:

```
<embed src="banner.swf?clickTAG=http://my-site.com&clickTARGET=_blank" height="250" width="300">
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the wrong thing was that i was using Flash 8, upper code is for Flash from 4 to 7.

Right way to do it in **Flash 4, 5, 6 or 7** in **ActionScript 2**:

```
on (release) { 
   if (clickTAG.substr(0,5) == "http:") { 
      getURL(clickTAG, clickTARGET); 
   } 
}
```

Right way to do it in **Flash 8 or 9** in **ActionScript 2**

```
on (release) { 
   if (_root.clickTAG.substr(0,5) == "http:") { 
      getURL(_root.clickTAG, _root.clickTARGET); 
   } 
}
```

The implementation in HTML is following.

With **embed tag**:

```
<embed src="path_to_swf.swf?clickTAG=http://website-to-open.com&clickTARGET=_blank" width="300" height="250">
```

Or with **object tag** which should be better practice:

```
<object type="application/x-schockwave-flash" data="path_to_swf.swf" width="300" height="250">
<param name="flashvars" value="clickTAG=http://website-to-open.com&clickTARGET=_blank">
</object>
```

Target _blank can also be replaced with _self or _top.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Actionscript 2. Not sure if you meant to; 
in Actionscript 3 you might code something like

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, go};
 function go(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if (clickTAG.substr(0,5) == "http:") {
    getURL(clickTAG, clickTARGET);
  }
)
```

Comment: I need to use Actionscript 2. It's a requirement. This code does just the same thing as mine. Only in actionscript 3.